# Most effective way to find repetitions in multiple object arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Say I have the following 3 arrays of objects:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 'Michael',

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => 'Kim',
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [Name] => 'George',
    )

)


Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 'Michael',

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => 'Kim',
    )

)


Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 'Michael',

    )
)
```

What is the most effective way to compare these 3 object arrays, and return the object(s) that occur in all 3? In this example, that would be the Michael object.

I have an unknown number of arrays with an unknown number of objects, but need to find the objects that occur in all of the arrays.

Comment: Loop all, calculate how much times it's repeated, filter results to leave only ones that is in all arrays.

Comment: Show what you've done so far

Comment: I don't know if you have some code to show already, but I guess that having other people write it for you, would be pretty effective :-)

Answer (score 1):

Php has a buit in function function for that and hence presumably faster.

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

**EDIT:** for that first you have to convert your object into arrays.

```
get_object_vars($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all 3 arrays while counting the occurrences of each ID in a 4th array. Following this, simply loop over your new array and report any occurrences with a count of 3.